# How can I make a palindrome ignore blank spaces. For my homework I need to modify this code and make it so it can read it as a palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome, deque

```
def palchecker(aString):
    chardeque = Deque()

    for ch in aString:
        chardeque.addRear(ch)
        

    stillEqual = True

    while chardeque.size() > 1 and stillEqual:
        first = chardeque.removeFront()
        last = chardeque.removeRear()
        if first != last:
            stillEqual = False

    return stillEqual

print(palchecker("lsdkjfskf"))
print(palchecker("radar"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and check out [ask]. Include your question as text in the body of the question itself, including expected output, current output, and how they differ.

Comment: If you want to ignore spaces then, well, do ignore them: skip them at the deque filling stage. Nothing more to say here.

Comment: I would recommend you familiarize yourself with available [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) in Python. Also, while there is no built in method to reverse strings, there is a [well known way to do it using slice notation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp).